# Alternate of Alt+F6 for Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> used to cycle between opened windows of same application in Windows XP but this does not seem to work in Win7. Is there any alternate shortcut for the same? I tried finding it on google but could not find any relevant result.

Comment: I've just tried Alt+F6 in MS Word 2007 on Win7 and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, pin the program to the taskbar.  Then press the **windows key + the numeric position** of the pinned icon.

For example, if first icon is task manager, second is windows explorer and 3rd is firefox.  Assuming you have multiple firefox windows opened, pressing **Windows + 3** will cycle you thru each firefox window.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts
and click on Windows logo key keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Or try a tool [like this.](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher/instance-switcher.html)

The shortcut for changing between windows of the same application would be Ctrl+`.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5037/vistaswitcher-is-a-ridiculously-awesome-alt-tab-replacement/